# How to proper use vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to exclude the `h1` tag every time I go to different route in my Vue application.

Here's my `app.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">

        <h1>LANDING PAGE</h1>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <!--Path for login.vue-->
        <button @click="$router.push('/login')">LOGIN</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'app',
    }
</script>
```

And here's my login page, where I want only to display my design for login page **only**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Login"
    }
</script>
```

My `route.js`:

```
import Login from './components/LandingPage/Login';
import Register from './components/LandingPage/Register';

export default [
    {
        path: '/login', component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/register', component: Register
    }
]
```

and lastly my `main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    /* To remove # in the URL */
    mode: 'history'
});
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    router: router
}).$mount('#app');
```

I didn't include the `register.vue` because it's just the same with `login.vue`.

Comment: Why don't you use a specific route just for landing page and another one for router-view? Or you can use just like Psidom said..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional rendering based on the landing page url:

```
<h1 v-if="$route.path === '/landing-page-url'">LANDING PAGE</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there are three approaches to solve your problem:

1. Just drop your `<h1></h1>` into your landing page component.
2. You can use conditional rendering, like **Psidom** answered (just changed `path` to `name`):
   `<h1 v-if="$route.name === 'Landing'">Landing page</h1>`
3. You can have only one `<h1></h1>` in your main layout, and render current page title dynamically. [Route Meta Fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) come in rescue.

```
import Login from './components/LandingPage/Login'
import Register from './components/LandingPage/Register'

export default [
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
          title: 'Login',
        },
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        component: Register,
        meta: {
          title: 'Register',
        },
    },
]
```

And then in your `template`:

```
<h1>{{ $route.meta.title }}</h1>
```

P.S. To navigate to another route in your template use [`<router-link></router-link>`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link) instead of `button` with `click` event.